# How can I use a href within a text attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the text attribute to show text on my website.
How would I make the text redirect me to a site when clicked?

This is what i currently have,

```
<div class="text abc" data-text="abc">
    abc
</div>
```

I've tried the following

```
  <div class="text abc" data-text="<b href='https://www.google.com'>abc</b>">
    abc
  </div>
```

But this would just turn the "href" into text too, it won't actually do what it is supposed to do. (redirect me to google)

Comment: Use javascript to open the link from your `data-text` attribute

Comment: use anchor tag : ```<a href='https://www.google.com'>abc</a>```

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve here. What's wrong with a plain `<a>`, what does this have to do with data attributes at all?

Comment: @deceze i think he is a neophyte

Comment: @axel Otherwise they probably wouldn't be here, sure. But there's still gotta be some reasoning behind taking this approach, I'd hope.

Comment: "I am using the text attribute to show text on my website." — That attribute won't do that. It is designed to provide data to custom software that processes it. If you want to alter your custom software to make a clickable link then you need to show us that software!

Comment: You are indeed correct haha. Sorry for my bad expression.

Comment: @deceze oh he explained under my answer that he don't want the words to appear like links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use anchor tag `<a/>`:

```
<div class="text abc" data-text="abc">
    <a href='https://www.google.com'>abs</a>
</div>
```

The way to remove undeline of anchor:

HTML:

```
<div class="text abc" data-text="abc">
    <a class="no-underline" href='https://www.google.com'>abs</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.no-underline a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, but it's putting adding a underline, is there a way to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: you can use CSS to style the hyperlink any way you like. I would suggest looking up a basic CSS tutorial. Styling hyperlinks is usually one of the first examples used. For example, removing the line is the CSS rule: `text-decoration: none;`

Answer (score 0):

you should use the anchor, thats the common way to make a link

```html
<a href='https://www.google.com'>Website</a>
```

If you don't want to use an  and dont have that blue link you'll need javascript and put an event on your div like

```
$('#myDivId').on('clik',function(){
//redirect with window location
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an anchor element.

```
  <div class="text abc">
    <a href='https://www.google.com'>abc</a>
  </div>
```

[MDN: The Anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)